# Create Chrooted user on debian

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, sftp, chroot

Hi I'm trying to create a user that has only sftp access to my server and no ssh access. These are the commands I use:

```
cd /home/
adduser [SFTP USER NAME]  
usermod -G sftp [SFTP USER NAME]
usermod -s /bin/false [SFTP USER NAME]
chown root:root /home/[SFTP USER NAME]
chmod 0755 /home/[SFTP USER NAME]
# usermod -d [SFTP USER FOLDER] [SFTP USER NAME]
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
# now add a folder the user can write into
mkdir home/[SFTP USER NAME/FOLDER]/private
# give permissions
chown [SFTP USER NAME]:[SFTP USER NAME] /home/[SFTP USER FOLDER]/private
```

and in my /etc/ssh/sshd_config I have a sftp group that has the right settings. Like in [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/chroot-users-with-openssh-an-easier-way-to-confine-users-to-their-home-directories/) guide.

Also I need to say that it already worked for other users.

I think I have some error in my documentation. Can somebody please have a look and tell me if something is missing or wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hm. I had a look into my bash history and it works like this:

```
cd /home/
adduser [SFTP USER NAME]
usermod -G sftp [SFTP USER NAME]
usermod -s /bin/false [SFTP USER NAME]
chown root:root [SFTP USER NAME]
chmod 0755 [SFTP USER NAME]
usermod -d [SFTP USER NAME/FOLDER] [SFTP USER NAME]
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
mkdir [SFTP USER NAME]/private
chown [SFTP USER NAME]:[SFTP USER NAME] [SFTP USER NAME]/private
```

I think the only difference is the `usermod -d` thing where I used instead of the full path to the folder the relative path.